# redux check for Array Mutations

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

i build my first react-redux app and i need help understanding if i mutante an array on my reducer function.

the action i am testing is selecting items :
update the "selected" boolean property according to the selection passed by the action

it is an array containing object :

```
    "allItems":[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "item1",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "item2",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "item3",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "item4",
        "selected": false
    }
]
```

now the reducer :

```
const allItems = (state=[], action) => {

switch(action.type){

    case "SELECT_ITEM" :

        return state.map( (item, index) => {
            if(item.id === action.payload.id){
                return { ...item, selected: true}
            }
            else
            {
                return {...item, selected: false}
            }
        })

    default:
    return state
    }

}
```

thank you

Comment: Is that a slice reducer for the `allItems` slice?

Comment: yes, on the first line it is suppose to be `const allItems = (state=[], action) => {` i will edit the question now

Comment: Ok, maybe you can describe how it is not working. For example, how is the state not as you expected after action is handled by reducer?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you return an `Object.assing({}, item, selected: true)` for example, this will ensure that you always return a new object with a new state.

Comment: thank you for your reply, following your suggestion i did that:

`case "SELECT_ITEM" :

return state.map((item, index) => {
if(item.id === action.payload.id){
    return Object.assign({}, item,{
        selected:true
    })
}else{
    return Object.assign({}, item,{
        selected:false
    })
}
})`

is it ok now ?